# NullPointerException in FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I'm using the Android compatibility library and occasionally get a weird `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:960)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:768)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.startPendingDeferredFragments(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:410)
    at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:103)
    at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:81)
    at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.onStartLoading(CursorLoader.java:126)
    at android.support.v4.content.Loader.startLoading(Loader.java:197)
    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.start(LoaderManager.java:262)
    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.doStart(LoaderManager.java:710)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onStart(Fragment.java:981)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1332)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:906)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1240)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:612)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:433)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:405)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:386)
    ...
```

Obviously, I'm doing **something** wrong to allow the `FragmentManager` to get into such a state where it can crash like this, but I have no clue what. The [relevant code](https://github.com/grantland/android-support-v4/blob/master/src/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#L960) in the `FragmentManagerImpl` is not offering me any clues. I'm guessing `mActivity` is somehow `null` at that point in the code? But that seems impossible as the activity is already on the screen and I'm not adding any fragments to it — just switching among them in a `ViewPager`.

Comment: include your code please

Comment: What code in particular would you like to see? None of it is anywhere in the stack trace.

Comment: all of it?  We can't help you out without code samples.  At the very minimum post wherever you use the `FragmentManager`.  Does the crash happen when you change fragments?  Post the code for how you change fragments. etc.

Comment: I have started to see this crash but **only** after obfuscation with ProGuard. Anymore advice going?

Comment: Edit- managed to get it without Proguard too...

Comment: This problem is explained at this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393693/android-fragmentmanager-backstackrecord-run-throwing-nullpointerexception

Comment: @seufagner the stack trace there is pretty clearly not the same as the one here, alas.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok guys, after hitting my head against a brick wall for a while on this I found that this was directly associated with my fragment's declaration of `setRetainInstance(true)`. After removing this the problems went away. This appears to be a compatibility library bug...

I will raise something under the appropriate Google project.
Best of luck if you are reading this slowly sobbering to yourself! I hope this will allow you to work around the problem.

Comment: I recently ran into the same thing, and I'm not using FragmentManager at all (just instantiating via xml). It only happens for me on a 2.3 device with a hardware keyboard. When I close the keyboard... kaboom.

Comment: +1. Ran into the same problem today :). Everything looked fine till that moment NPE @`FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()` when switching between fragments after orientation was changed. :)))). JFYI it happened on 4.1.1.

Comment: Really looks like a compatibility lib bug. Have you raised it somewhere? If yes, please link to it so we can vote on it.

Comment: nearly 3 years later and removing setRetainInstance(true) seems to have done the trick. Thanks Oceanlife

Answer (score 5):

I got this error a few days ago and was quite confounded, but I figured out that it was because a `FragmentTransaction` didn't seem to get any pending transactions so when calling `executePendingTransactions();` A `NPE` much like this one was thrown.
I solved it by making sure that every transaction actually changed something (i.e add fragment 1 -> remove fragment 1 -> commit/execute would not work).
Also make sure that none of the fragments in the pager have become `null`.

Comment: I've just tried adding executePendingTransactions repeatedly, and couldn't get it to crash, but I still get these crash very rarely without knowing why

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error because I was referencing an instance of a fragment in a view pager adapter rather that the fragment itself.

Creating a new instance of the fragment each time the fragment was called resolved this error.  Obviously this is proper programming but just in case some other noobs are making that mistake....

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(position == 0)
        return new Walkthrough_Fragment_1();
    if(position == 1)
        return new Walkthrough_Fragment_4();
    if(position == 2)
        return new Walkthrough_Fragment_2();
    else{
        return new  Walkthrough_Fragment_3();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This bug occurs when using `FragmentPagerAdapter` inside a Fragment that use `setRetainInstance(true)`.

If you want to maintain the `setRetainInstance(true)` you can use @Marc answer from [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19099987/4344807):

```
@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
    //do nothing here! no call to super.restoreState(arg0, arg1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point You are using instance of FragmentManager class, which is not initialized. Find that point and initialize object properly.

Comment: Yes, that solved it for me.  Just initialize FragmentManager in onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

I just read that you can not perform certain transactions on Fragments that were added at compile time. For example, if your Fragment was defined in XML and you try to replace it, boom.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my issue by making my **FragmentManager as a static global variable, then  initialized it in your onCreate method**. I found out that using getSupportFragmentManager()
 everywhere in your code can result this exception, because getSupportFragmentManager() may point to your older fragment manager value and may not be referenced.

Here is a example:

```
  public class yourClass{

      private static FragmentManager myFragmentManagerSupport; 
      ...

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          myFragmentManagerSupport = this.getSupportFragmentManager();

              ....

          }

         /*Then reuse myFragmentManagerSupport  everywhere you needed instead of  
         *                     getSupportFragmentManager()
         */

    }
```

Hope it help.