# Is it a good practice to user Fragment.setRetainInstance to not handle recreation?

Tags: android

Is it a good practice to use `Fragment.setRetainInstance()` for all of your `Fragments` in order to get rid yourself of handling `Fragment`s recreation, saving instances states, etc? Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use it with fragments not in the back stack if they have to retain configuration changes. It just make things simpler.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550351/1300995

Comment: how can we retain configuration changes in fragments which are maintain in back stack. As we cannot use `setRetainInstance(true)`

Answer (score 2):

It's not always good, no. By retaining the instance you are telling 'ye old Android to give you that exact same instance of a `Fragment` back, i.e. the Fragment's `onDestroy` is never called rather it is onAttach(ed) and onDetach(ed).

Regularly, you need to re-flow the views to take advantage of a different screen ratio as a result of an orientation change (for example) and having your fragment retaining it's state will mean that the framework will not attempt to use your "landscape friendly" views if started in portrait mode for example.

The affects of `onRetainInstance` are subtle, it's no silver bullet. Wield with care.

Comment: how can we retain configuration changes in fragments which are maintain in back stack. As we cannot use `setRetainInstance(true)`

Comment: This is not true, even if you call `setRetainInstance(true)` on your fragment, its `onCreateView()` method will be called again, (and therefore it will be layout again with the new configuration.

Comment: Just reconfirmed the behaviour and I can see what @nbarraille is referring. Previously when I wrote this answer in 2012 if you had two layouts for a fragment set in onCreateView under different resource qualifiers -port or -land, then by using setRetainInstance(true) would mean that the starting layout would be reused across screen rotations. This does not appear to be the case anymore. Rest assured there were mainly subtle problems with this call previously;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456077/nullpointerexception-in-fragmentmanager/