# Android null pointer exception in fragments

Tags: android

I am using  a `ViewPager` with fragments .I get a **null pointer exception** when the screen orientation is changed to landscape.A different layout is used for landscape

The exception is :

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Stack trace:-

```
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{inc.mine.Customtracker/inc.mine.Customtracker.TabsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{inc.mine.Customtracker/inc.mine.Customtracker.ChartActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5005)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{inc.mine.Customtracker/inc.mine.Customtracker.ChartActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1992)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:706)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:350)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at inc.mine.Customtracker.TabsActivity.addTab(TabsActivity.java:59)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at inc.mine.Customtracker.TabsActivity.setTabs(TabsActivity.java:36)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at inc.mine.Customtracker.TabsActivity.onCreate(TabsActivity.java:30)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    ... 12 more
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at inc.mine.Customtracker.ChartFragment.onCreateView(ChartFragment.java:64)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1065)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1844)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:519)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1195)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4553)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-18 20:31:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(32205):    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Could You provide more logcat output? probably similar to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19917 .

Comment: can you please post: ChartFragment.java line 64

Comment: Impossible to guess without code, but this is most likely due to wrong initialization. When you change orientation, Activity is restarted. You should save the activity state and restore it.

Comment: @sandrstar Agreed. Probably that- or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456077/nullpointerexception-in-fragmentmanager/11448991#11448991) - The difference being the latter occurs intermittently rather than on every rotation change...

Comment: @m0skit0 can you please put your comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to wrong initialization. When you change orientation, `Activity` is restarted. You should save the activity state and restore it.