# Android FragmentManager BackStackRecord.run throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I sometimes get the following exception when working with Fragments:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:591)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The exception occurs when `run()` of `BackStackRecord` is called through `execPendingTransactions()`, when it tries to remove a fragment from the manager.

```
case OP_REMOVE: {
  Fragment f = op.fragment;
  f.mNextAnim = op.exitAnim; <----
  mManager.removeFragment(f, mTransition, mTransitionStyle);
}
break;
```

I can't seem to figure out what exactly is causing this? I think it has to do with the backstack of fragments not being cleaned up right when removing fragments.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Answering my own question:

**This exception is (eventually) thrown when you call `FragmentTransaction.remove(null);` and `FragmentTransaction.commit();`**

**EDIT: And also, like Twice Circled and shinyuX point out in the comment; when calling the `show(null)` or `add(null)`, `attach(null)` and `detach(null)` methods, and probably also `hide(null)`**

After calling `commit()`, the transaction will be queued in the FragmentManager. As a result, when the operation is being processed after you explicitly call `FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()`, or when the FragmentManager queue thread calls it, it throws a `NullPointerException`.

In my case, I was maintaining fragment states in a global object. There I checked if the fragment was showing or not, and then removed visible fragments. But because I started a new FragmentActivity, these states were still set to true while they were not visible. So this is a design error.

Other than fixing the design error, the solution was simple: check whether `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()` returned `null` before removing the fragment.

Comment: Good answer - This helped me solve my own issue. One thing to note, you will get the same error when you call FragmentTransaction.show(null), .hide(null) etc. not just .remove(null). Hopefully this will help others track down their issue.

Comment: Helped me A LOT ! Note that it'll fail with any action sent with a null fragment (in my case `attach` `detach`

Comment: Thanks for this, definitely helped. In my case I was navigating back to a destroyed FragmentActivity where I kept references to fragments in fields. The solution was to use `findFragmentByTag` and re-assign these fields on the activity's onCreate method  - if `savedInstanceState != null` (in which case the fragments wouldn't have been recreated - see pattern [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)).

Comment: this should totally crash on the actual `hide`,`show`... call, so that the stacktrace is actually usable ...

Comment: Couldn't agree more @njzk2

Comment: I call "replace" and the parameter isn't null. How come I still get this issue?

Comment: .hide(null) in my case

Answer (score 0):

The one reason why it happens it is invoking

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment)
```

while `fragment` is null

Answer (score -2):

I don't use tag to create the fragments (they works like TabBar containers).

So, it works when change Tab, but if I press back button I got the same error.

At onDestroyView method I found fragment instance with FragmentManager#findFragmentById, however FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag returns null, sure.

```
class MyFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    if (this.mapFragment != null
            && getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    this.mapFragment.getId()) != null) {

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this.mapFragment)
                .commit();
        this.mapFragment = null;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to set mapFragment to null?

Comment: A question worth answering :- `Why is it necessary to set mapFragment to null?`