# Android Getting NullPointerException before OnCreate is called of my MainActivity

Tags: android

I was developing an Android app and while modifying a Fragment's code, I am now getting hard crashes whenever I try to launch the app.  The strange this is, the NullPointerException is being thrown before it ever actually reaches my code, as when I go into debug mode the Exception is thrown before I reach OnCreate() for my MainActivity.  Particularly baffling is I wasn't messing with anything in either the MainActivity nor its layout.

Stack trace below.  Any ideas?

```
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.legacy/com.example.legacy.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:656)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1481)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1866)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:568)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5189)
07-30 15:39:52.753: E/AndroidRuntime(5348):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260059/nullpointerexception-on-backstack

Answer (score 0):

IF this is pre Honeycomb then YOU MUST use the support library (I think you are doing this already).

IF you are using the support library fragments then YOU MUST use a FragmentActivity and not an Activity from which to launch your fragments.

IF you are using setRetainInstance(true) then please would you remove it and try again.

(This is the link I suggested that actually helped resolve the problem):

[Android FragmentManager BackStackRecord.run throwing NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393693/android-fragmentmanager-backstackrecord-run-throwing-nullpointerexception)

Comment: I'm already using the support library, and my MainActivity already extends FragmentActivity.

Comment: Good. Please look at this which MAY be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393693/android-fragmentmanager-backstackrecord-run-throwing-nullpointerexception

Comment: Oh - are you using setRetainInstance(true) ?

Comment: I'm not calling setRetainInstance(true) manually anywhere, so unless something else is calling it I'm not.

Comment: Sheldon, that was it.  Apparently any call off of FragmentTransaction (like FragmentTransaction.remove(null)) crashes the application and prevents you from even debugging.  Nasty bug, I'm surprised they allow  that.

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact same issue, and none of the suggestions above helped me.
What did help me was examining the imports for my fragments:

> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.ViewGroup;
> import android.app.Fragment;
>
> public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment{

As can be seen, the import for Fragment is **android.app.Fragment**
when it should be **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**.
So changing the code as follows resolved my issue:

> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.ViewGroup;
> import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
>
> public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment{

The first import is probably added automatically by Eclipse.

Comment: What fixed my problem was actually posted by another user as a comment (and apparently they chose to delete their comment?  I hadn't noticed that until now).  But since this seems to be a fix I think it's worthwhile leaving it up.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably trying to run `fragment activity` on an emulator with Android version lower than `HoneyComb 3.0`. So for running fragment activity you have to have a phone or emualtor running Android 3.0 or later. You will have to add a supporting library `android-support-v4.jar` in your project. Once you have incorporated that library this issue will be gone.

Comment: Isn't the support library already there? You see it in the stack dump

Comment: As talkol noted, I already have the library included in my project.

Further, I've been able to run this app before, so I'm not sure why this exception is suddenly popping up.