# findFragmentById return null

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

When I call `findFragmentById()` with the id of my fragment, it returns `null`.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <fragment android:name="com.madduck.test.app.fragment.MainFragment"
                  android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <fragment android:name="com.madduck.test.app.fragment.LoginFragment"
                  android:id="@+id/login_fragment"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private static final int LOGIN = 0;
private static final int MAIN = 1;
private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = MAIN +1;
private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT]

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragments[LOGIN] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.login_fragment);
    fragments[MAIN] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (Fragment f : fragments) {
        if (f != null)
            transaction.hide(f);
        else
            Log.e(TAG, "???");
    }

    transaction.commit();
}
```

The thing is that when I call `fm.findFragmentById(R.id.login_fragment);` I get a `null` but when I call `fm.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);` I get the fragment.

Comment: Post the complete crash log and your fragment code

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I found the solution (was using support.v4 in one fragment and the normal type in the other one)  I can't post the solution right now, because i don't have 10 reputations, but will answer myself tomorrow.  I search a bit before and I found nothing related to that.

Comment: I suspect that could be the issue. Any way your found it . Good

Answer (score 37, accepted):

just found out my mistake.

In my MainActivity.java i was importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` and in my LoginFragment.java i was importing `android.app.Fragment;`.  I changed it to the same thing and `fm.findFragmentById(R.id.login_fragment)` now return the right fragment.

Comment: I wasted all day trying to find an answer to a similar problem, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the insight. In my case using getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager() solved the problem as my underlying fragment was from support package.

Comment: Holy heck ... waste of time too. Think Jetbrains is a bit overzealous about importing what it _thinks_ is right. I've seen this in C# with Rider before.

Answer (score 104):

The answer [Kar0t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23368288/619587) is perfectly  fine but this may help somebody. On my case I had a fragment inside of a fragment and I was getting the wrong FragmentManager. I just had to call:

`getChildFragmentManager()`

and then just find the Fragment as usual:

```
fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment)
```

Comment: I was struggling here also. Thank you so much!

Comment: Working! When I use <fragment> tag to add fragment in fragment, getChildFragmentManager() is worked and getFragmentManager() is not worked. And If I added fragment using getFragmentManager() promatically in parent fragment , getFragmentManager() is worked. Then If I add fragment in fragment promatically , I have to use getChildFragmentManager()?

Comment: @inhogo For adding `Fragment` both works, but for finding `Fragment`, if you are inside `Fragmnet`, you have to use `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 7):

Not really related to the specific question but related to receiving `null` on `findFragmentById`, if you call `findFragmentById` immediately after commit it will return null or the last fragment(before commit), the reason because commit do async request.

From docs:

> Schedules a commit of this transaction. The commit does not happen
>   immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be
>   done the next time that thread is ready.

If you need to `findFragmentById` immediately, for example change status bar text color after adding fragment, call `executePendingTransactions()` after `commit()`

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
//call findFragmentById
```

Answer (score 4):

## Kotlin

I also had problem because I was in a child fragment. I could use:

```
    supportFragmentManager.fragments.forEach {
        it.childFragmentManager.fragments.forEach { fragment ->
            if (fragment is HomeFragment) {
                //do something
            } 
        }
```

but one coworker optimized it with :

```
     if( findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).currentDestination?.id == R.id.homeFragment) {
       // do something
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem because my project has two layout with the same file name. eg. In your case, I have two `activity_main.xml` in different modules.

So somehow it get compiled and when you run

> fm.findFragmentById(R.id.login_fragment)

then it is looking for the fragment in the other `activity_main.xml`, which is null.

If this is the case, just check your file names of layouts, make sure they are unique.

Hope this help anyone with the same issue as mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is android life everyday something DEPRICATED, we are looking to samples and manual but they already not working)

My issue was in mix "import android.app.Fragment;" with modern "androidx.fragment.app.Fragment". Below sample for androidx

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

            Fragment myFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frgmContainer);
            if(myFrag==null)
                return;
            ((TextView) myFrag.getView().findViewById(R.id.textView))
                    .setText("Access to Fragment 2 from Activity");
```