# Error inflating map View

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

Map Null point exception error. Having trouble loading  the map in my fragment. Seems to always be null.  I have tried loading the view in different ways but still seems to get a null map.

```
08-01 12:41:19.349: E/AndroidRuntime(25728): Process: com.ideamovinganddelivery, PID: 25728
08-01 12:41:19.349: E/AndroidRuntime(25728): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 12:41:19.349: E/AndroidRuntime(25728):    at com.idealmovinganddelivery.mapfragment.MapsFragment.setUpMapIfNeeded(MapsFragment.java:122)
08-01 12:41:19.349: E/AndroidRuntime(25728):    at com.idealmovinganddelivery.mapfragment.MapsFragment.onResume(MapsFragment.java:90)
```

Main Activity

```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener,MapDialogFragment.MapDialogListener{
        @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, String Address) {
        MapsFragment mapFrag= (MapsFragment)     getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
         mapFrag.addDeliveryPoint(Address); 
    }
```

Fragment_map XML

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_map_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.idealmovinganddelivery.MainActivity" >

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/map"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         class="com.idealmovinganddelivery.mapfragment.MapsFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Map Fragment

```
       public class MapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
    OnMarkerClickListener
    {
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true) ;


        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container,
                false);
            return view;
        }
public static void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (map == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) MainActivity.fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (map != null)
                setUpMap();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct. You cannot cast `SupportMapFragment` to `MapsFragment` here.

At the point where you are performing this cast, you are finding the view with ID `R.id.map`. You have defined this in your xml file to have the type SupportMapFragment here:

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

You should define the `<Fragment>` element to use your `SupportMapFragment` subclass, `MapsFragment` instead:

```
fragment
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     class="com.idealmovinganddelivery.mapfragment.MapsFragment" />
```

Comment: I fixed that and now the inflate method is giving me an error inflating the fragment message at the line of the xml file I changed.

Comment: Seems the map throws an null point exception. I updated the error log in my original post reflecting the new error.

Comment: You'll need to post the code of your MapsFragment class, I can't tell what happens on line 122 where the exception occurs.

Comment: Tried posting the code  but said my post had too much code and not enough text. 
Line 122  is map = ((SupportMapFragment) MainActivity.fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: You should probably ask a new question since this seems like a new problem. But it sounds like either you have not called setContentView before line 122 executes or perhaps you are importing the wrong Fragment or FragmentManager as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23368288/815679). Make sure that you are using Support Fragments if you are working with `SupportMapFragment`.