# I can't call my fragment method in my activity and I want to call 2 method in 2 different fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am a beginner. I am programming a weather app in android. I want to call fragment method in activity, but it have a error

And my main activity code here:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager viewpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewpager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        MyFragmentAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new WeatherCurrentFragment();
            case 1:
                return new WeatherForeCastFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 2;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.weather, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.change_city){
            showInputDialog();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showInputDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Change city");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        builder.setView(input);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                changeCity(input.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    public void changeCity(String city){
         WeatherCurrentFragment cf = (WeatherCurrentFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.currentweather);
         cf.updateWeatherData(city);
         WeatherForeCastFragment ff = (WeatherForeCastFragmen)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.forecast);
         ff.updateWeatherData(city);
         new CityPreference(this).setCity(city);
    }
}
```

And is show an error

```
07-18 08:59:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(2114): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void example.giaodien1.WeatherCurrentFragment.updateWeatherData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

As you see I want to call method one from CurrentWeatherFragment and one from ForecastWeatherFragment when I click button.

Answer (score 2):

Code following:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.currentweather);
```

return a null object reference.

This question may help you, [findFragmentById return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353344/findfragmentbyid-return-null)

By the way normally callback interface is used instead of calling a method that belongs to fragment in an activity like this:

```
public interface OnCityChangedListener(){
    public void onCityChanged(String city);
}
```

Implement this interface in Fragment:

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnCityChangedListener
```

and override this method in Fragment:

```
@override
public void onCityChanged(String city){
    updateWeatherData(city);
}
```

Instantiate fragments in activity, use an `ArrayList` to save them in activity, pass this `ArrayList` to constructor of `PageAdapter`,

```
public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> fs) {
    super(fm);
    this.fs = fs;
}
```

When clicking button to change city:

```
public void changeCity(String city){
    fs.onCityChanged(city);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `FragmentPagerAdapter` is managing fragments via `FragmentManager` that is passed to `FragmentPagerAdapter` constructor.

So than you call `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` there is no guarantee that it does not return `null`.

Better designed approach is to make `CityPreference` singleton object and instantiate it in `Application.onCreate()` method:

```
public class WeatherApplication extends Application {
    private static WeatherApplication instance;
    private CityPreference cityPreference;

    public static WeatherApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        cityPreference = new CityPreference(this);
    }

    public CityPreference getCityPreference() {
        return cityPreference;
    }    
}
```

Then you should add listeners for "city changed" event:

```
class CityPreference {
    public CityPreference(Context context) {
        // initialize SharedPreferences or any other storage
    }

    private final List<CityChangedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addListener(CityChangedListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(CityChangedListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        // save city to shared preferences or some other place

        for (listener: listeners) {
            listener.onCityChanged();
        }
    }

    public interface CityChangedListener {
        void onCityChanged();
    }
}
```

In each of your fragments make these changes:

```
class WeatherCurrentFragment extends Fragment implements CityChangedListener {
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        onCityChanged(); // force fragment update because city could be changed when fragment was hidden or even not yet created
        WeatherApplication.getInstance().getCityPreference().addListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        WeatherApplication.getInstance().getCityPreference().removeListener(this);
    }

    public void onCityChanged() {
        // update fragment
    }
}
```

And finally your `MainActivity.changeCity()` method:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    // other code

    private void changeCity(String city) {
        WeatherApplication.getInstance().getCityPreference().setCity(city);
    }
}
```