# YouTube Player crashes (java.lang.NullPointerException, null object reference)

Tags: java, android, youtube

my YouTube Player crashes and I do not know why.

This is my Java Code:
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    playerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment);
    playerFragment.initialize(YouTubeKey, this);
}



@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    mPlayer = youTubePlayer;

    //Enables automatic control of orientation
    mPlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION);

    //Show full screen in landscape mode always
    mPlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);

    //System controls will appear automatically
    mPlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI); 

    if (!b) {
        mPlayer.cueVideo("xxx");
        mPlayer.loadVideo("xxx");
    }
    else
    {
        mPlayer.play();
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    mPlayer = null;
    String ausgabe = youTubeInitializationResult.toString();
    Log.d("hi", ausgabe);
} }
```

Problem was solved

Comment: What does the fragment XML look like for (R.id.youtube_player_fragment)?

Comment: Because I have   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> in my content_youtube.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now we need some additional information to definitively answer this question, but it appears that this line is returning null, which suggests that you want to take a look at your resource XML and make sure you're grabbing the fragment properly.

`getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment);`

You may benefit from taking a look at this related question:

[findFragmentById return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353344/findfragmentbyid-return-null)

---

I suspect that the problem may be that in your resources XML, you're not declaring the fragment using the support library.

Try using:

```
<fragment
  android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
```

Comment: I thought the method playerFragment.initialize(YouTubeKey, this); is returning null, isnt it?

Comment: @FabianSawischa I added an edit to my answer.  Have you tried switching the name in your layout to use the support library?

Comment: Thanks mate! You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of these suggestions but none worked for me. I finally ended up creating a container and then replacing it at runtime with the YouTubeFragment. This worked perfectly fine for me.

1. Created a containerView in my layout file as, please note its just a part of my layout file

   ```
   <View
       android:padding="10dp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:background="@color/gray90"/>



   <FrameLayout
       android:padding="20dp"
       android:id="@+id/youtubeContent"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   ```
2. Then I created an instance of the youtube fragment as below

   youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
3. I then replaced it using the standard way as below:-

   FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
       transaction.replace(R.id.youtubeContent,youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

I hope this helps others