# Odd logcat error when switching to new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I haven't encountered a stack trace such as this. It's particularly weird because I can only get the error to be thrown when debugging. (Running the app *without* debugging does not yield this error). This happens upon selecting a particular page from my navigation drawer. I have just recently switched from activities to fragments and I may not have handled my fragment transactions correctly. I would appreciate any input! Thanks a lot guys, happy holidays!

Here's the stack trace:

```
Process: com.kohlerbear.whowascnscalc, PID: 2415
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'boolean android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.mAddToBackStack' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:685)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPeerrorndingActions(FragmentManager.java:1479)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:740)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5223)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

And here is how I am handling my fragment change (Not sure if this is the problem, just judging by the fact that the trace mentions the backstack). The app crashes (again, only when debugging)  regardless of whether or not I call `ft.addToBackStack(null)` .

```
Fragment frag = new ThirdScreenFragment(); 
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();`
```

Any ideas and input are appreciated :)

Comment: May be similar in nature to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393693/android-fragmentmanager-backstackrecord-run-throwing-nullpointerexception

Comment: and is `frag` or `ft` are null by any chance?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue. Put a breakpoint in the `android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run()` method and set break condition to `false`.

[image]

Comment: How did you think to do that??  Thank you!

Answer (score 26):

I recently ran into the same error message in Android studio. I could run my application but once I tried to start debugging, I would receive "Attempt to read from field 'boolean android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.mAddToBackStack' on a null object reference". The solution was to select in Android Studio, Run (toolbar) -> View Break Points -> disable each break point one by one until debugging started to work again. Doing this doesn't remove the break point entirely it simply disables them, so there's no need to worry that you'd need to remove all your break points to find the one causing the issue. It seems that one of the break points I had setup in a IntentService class was causing the issue. I'm not sure why it was causing an issue, but it seemed to fix this error for me.

Comment: Worked for me too. But seems to be bug in Android Studio. My version is 1.2.2

Comment: Worked for mee too, in Android 2.0 Preview.