# Passing from one fragment to another

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm trying here to create a menu, that passes from a fragment to another on click. When I press the specific item(activity) in the menu the activity exits, and the faults are

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();// this line has the problem
```

This is my complete logcat:

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
> ```
>
> at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:414)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:449)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:441)
>   atbr.exemplozxingintegration.MainActivity.selectDrawerItem(MainActivity.java:84
>   atbr.exemplozxingintegration.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:50)
>   at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:150)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:308)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18395)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        txResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txResult);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById (R.id.nvView);
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);}



    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
        // position
        Fragment fragment = null;

        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = MainActivity.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                fragmentClass = SecondActivity.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                fragmentClass = ThirdActivity.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = MainActivity.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

   // @Override
   // protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //     super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
   //
```

SecondActivity.java

```
 private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
        // position
        Fragment fragment = null;

        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = MainActivity.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                fragmentClass = SecondActivity.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                fragmentClass = ThirdActivity.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = SecondActivity.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // @Override
    // protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //     super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // }
```

Comment: Do you get any error in logcat? Please post that.

Comment: This is the logcat error : FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please post complete log cat in you question.

Comment: Added the complete logcat @Rohit5k2

Comment: Which line is line# 84? Error is at **MainActivity.java:84**

Comment: @Rohit5k2 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

Comment: Is `SecondActivity.java` a fragment or activity.

Comment: Have you checked [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13395157/1239911) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear as you have not posted your complete class code, and what error you are getting.

What i have understand is that you want to change fragment when an item in Navigation Drawer is selected. Similar to **Gmail** app, when a user move from inbox folder to sent folder or any other.

If you are trying to do same, you need to make one Activity, insert a fragment. When an item in navigation drawer is selected, the current fragment should be replaced by the new fragment according to the option selected in navigation drawer.

Check the following two links, that will give you the whole idea.

Link1:  https://androidbelieve.com/material-navigation-drawer-with-header/

Link2: http://joerichard.net/android/android-how-to-change-fragments-when-navigation-drawer-item-selected/

Answer (score 0):

[FragmentTransaction.replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29)
calls `remove(Fragment)` and then `add(int, Fragment, String)` to actually replace the fragment. So in your case it might occur that there is **no** fragment in the container view and hence you are calling `remove(null)`. So check if you have to add or replace a fragment.

you can check if there is any fragment in the container view and proceed accordingly:

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 android.support.v4.app.Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.flContent);
 if(currentFragment==null){ 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
 }else{
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
 }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: What is flContainer?

Comment: It is there in your code: I think id of your `FrameLayout` where you are adding your fragment to.

Comment: It was a typo in the first line. Edited.

Comment: It cannot resolve fragmentManager#. And sorry if I post stupid questions, this si my 1st time programming android

Comment: That's okay. Its not a stupid question.

Check edit.

Comment: It doesn't work, and I forgot to add that my other activis, are activities and not fragments.